# Xcode: AutoLayout/Storyboard with UICollectionView Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

**SHORT QUESTION:** Is there a correlation between the "View As" functionality on the Storyboard in Xcode and the way your App appears visually in the simulator?

---

**LONG QUESTION:** 
I'm working on a Schedule app, and in the app there is a CollectionView at the top of the ViewController that allows you to select a date to load a schedule for i.e you can select tomorrow to plan your schedule, you can select today, yesterday or days further in past or future.

In my project, I have this code in place, to select the current date.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        dateCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: CalendarModel.CURRENT_DAY, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
}
```

Now, the weird thing occurs when I run the project. If I select the iPhone 11 as the "View as" in the Storyboard like this:

[image]

And then run the iPhone 11 Simulator, my App works and it looks like this: 
[image]

Now, if I select the iPhone SE in the Storyboard as such:

[image]

And then run the app on the iPhone 11, it looks like this (not working, not showing "Today"):

[image]

Now the strange thing occurs, if I now select the iPhone 8, which is the same size as the iPhone SE while still having the iPhone SE selected in the storyboard. It'll now work, as you can see:

[image]

If I also have the iPhone SE selected in the "View As" section and try and run it on my physical iPhone XS, I get the same issue.

So my question is, is this an Xcode bug? And let's say I hypothetically released this App on the Appstore, would it only work on some devices? Is there a way to prevent this?

Here I have posted a Minimal Reproducible Example on GitHub:

[github.com/julianboyko/Power-Planner-MRE](http://github.com/julianboyko/Power-Planner-MRE)

I'm almost certain it's a Storyboard issue, that has something to do with the StackView I have to use, and the constraints used.

Thank you.

Comment: Tough to say with only the info you've provided. Review [mre] ... it will be much easier to offer help with an actual runnable example.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks Don. I created a Minimal Reproducible Example right here: https://github.com/julianboyko/Power-Planner-MRE
The CollectionView is inside a StackView just as it is in my original project. The error started to appear as I started adding constraints, which leads me to believe it has something to do with that. I put it on GitHub because I don't think I can show Storyboard constraints on here. Could you let me know what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling:

```
dateCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: CalendarModel.CURRENT_DAY, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
```

inside `viewWillAppear()`, at which point auto-layout has not yet determined the frames.

Instead, you need to call it *after* all the views have been laid-out. Comment-out your entire `viewWillAppear()` func, and try it this way:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    dateCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: CalendarModel.CURRENT_DAY, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. This was driving me nuts. The only thing now, is it scrolls when the View Appears, which is rather ugly. Is there any work around off the top of your head that you can think of so the user doesn't see that? If not, that's fine. But if you do it would help a bunch.

Comment: Check my answer a little closer... `animated: false` :)

Comment: My mistake! I can't thank you enough. Seriously man. You were a massive help.

Comment: @Julian - happy to be of help. By the way... good job on your [mre] . Folks tend to put ***way too much*** code in there.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean your build using cmd+shift+k? It probably won't do anything but couldn't hurt to try. Also on the second screenshot it isn't positioned equally but programmatically set it to center, have you checked all constraints(and again don't know why that would change the displayed style but worth a shot).

Comment: Yeah I have tried cleaning the project, the issue still persists. Also if you look at the first picture, that's the iPhone 11 which is the same as the second picture and it's centered correctly. The reason is, when an item is selected it automatically centers, and in the viewDidAppear I select an item. So that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The various devices in the simulator each have their own state. Your app may be installed on some of them and not on others, and the app’s state on each of the devices on which it’s installed is specific to that device.

It looks like your app defaults to showing the current date, but it also saves the selected date and uses that the next time it runs. That’d be pretty reasonable behavior, at any rate, so for the sake of argument let’s say that’s what it does. If you ran your app on the iPhone 11 simulator last week, then perhaps your app saved that day as the selected date. When you ran it again recently on other devices where it wasn’t installed, the app started “fresh” and chose the current date. But when you ran it on the iPhone 11, the app already had some saved data, so it used that instead of falling back to the default behavior.

Note that this will be the case even if you rebuilt the app and installed it again on the iPhone 11 simulator. When you rebuild the app, Xcode installs the new app but leaves the apps’sexisting data in place, just as though you were updating the app from the App Store. If you want the app to launch as though it were newly installed, just delete it from the simulator before building.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense but unfortunately that isn't the case here. The app doesn't save the selected date, and instead at launch it defaults to today's date. The app has an array of dates. It holds 15 days. The current date, the following week and the previous week. On launch it always defaults to the current date because since it's a daily planner, it should always show the current date. Unfortunately, the app on certain devices (depending on which screen size I pick in Storyboard), scrolls to the beginning of the date collectionview, even though you can tell it selected today's date.

Comment: You can tell it selected today's date, because it highlights the date when selected, and as you can see, when it scrolls to the beginning of the DateCollectionView, it shows no items highlighted. I have my code publicly posted on GitHub if you'd be willing to take a look? It'd be a huge help, as I'm pretty stuck here. https://github.com/julianboyko/Power-Planner 

You can find the code in the ScheduleVC class, in the ViewControllers folder..

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the affected simulators and reinstalling?

Comment: I have indeed. I think for some reason, there is a weird correlation between the Storyboard's "View as" and the way the app displays on a device (both simulator and physical as I've tested it on my own phone as well)